# Countable unions and the whole real line R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

It has been a while since  my undergraduate introductory analysis course, so I am a little rusty. I know that to show two sets $B, C$ are equal, you first show that $B\subseteq C$ and then $C\subseteq B$ . To show $B\subseteq C$ you take any element of $B$, say $b \in B$ and show that $b \in C$.

The main issue I have is actually doing this for some inclusions. Like using the Archimedean Property and so on. Now to my question:

How would you show, for $a,b\in \Bbb{R}$ with $a<b$, that  $$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]=(a,b)$$

where $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$ is a countable union of half open intervals.

Also how would you show that  $$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-n,n)=\Bbb{R}$$
Note $n\in\Bbb{N}$ here.

Edit 1:
For the second one, I think I have the direction $\Bbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-n,n)$.

Consider $x\in\Bbb{R}$. We have three cases $x>0$ and $x<0$ and $x=0$. 
For $x=0$, we have that for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $-n<0<n$ so $0\in\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-n,n)$.

Now for any positive real number ,there exists an $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $N\leq x < N+1$.

Now for $x<0$ we have that $-x>0$. By what I stated previously, there exists $m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $m\leq -x < m+1$ . So $-m-1 < -x \leq -m <m+1$ and so $x \in(-m-1, m+1)$. Thus $x \in\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-n,n)$. 
The case for $x>0$ is similar.

But I am unsure of how to show the other inclusion $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-n,n)\subseteq\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Have you made any attempt? tell us where you have difficulty.

Comment: Please see my edits. I shall have a go at the first one in a few minutes.

Comment: It is difficult to guess where exactly you have problems.  Do you have problem in understanding what the union in the last line stands for? People can help you if they can guess where exactly are the holes in your understanding.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was thinking about $\Bbb{R}$ being a subset of the countable union for a while. I think I am unsure of the countable union being a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ . It does seem trivial, but I feel that there might be some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\exists x \in (a,b)$ s.t. $x \notin\bigcup_{n=1} ^{\infty}(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$

Then $b-\frac{1}{n}<x$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

But $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b-\frac{1}{n}=b$$ which implies that $b \leq x$ by algebra of limits which is a contradiction.

Hence $(a,b) \subset \bigcup_{n=1} ^{\infty}(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$

Similarly you can prove the other direction.

The second problem is proven simialrly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know when two sets are equal?

Say $B=(a,b)$ and $$A=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$$ You must prove $A=B$.

So take any $x\in A$ and prove that it is also in $B$. Then do vice versa.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of this technique. I forgot to mention this in my question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

By double inclusion. For the first question, because for any positive integer $n$, we clearly have $(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]\subset(a,b)$, we know that $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]\subset (a,b)$

Now consider any element $x \in (a,b)$. Then, $x<b$ and because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b-\frac{1}{n}=b$, by very definition of the limit, we know that there is some integer $n$ such that $x<b-\frac{1}{n}<b$. Hence, $x\in (a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$. It follows that $(a,b)\subset \bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$, so we are done.

With a similar reasoning, one can show your second question concerning $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi Suzet, the part I am stuck on is where you conclude that $x<b-1/n<b$. How did you get this from the definition of limit? Are you thinking about limits of sequences?

Comment: Yes exactly. The sentence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b-\frac{1}{n}=b$ says that for any positive real number $\epsilon >0$, there is an integer $N$ such that for every integer $n> N$, $|(b-\frac{1}{n})-b|=\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon$. Then, take $\epsilon = b-x >0$ and you are done. Indeed, for $n$ big enough, you then have $\frac{1}{n}<b-x$ so that $x<b-\frac{1}{n}$. (Actually, because the $b$'s cancel out when one writes down the inequality from the definition of the limit, we really see that what is important is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I just need help with one more thing. You say "for $n$ big enough" that's from $n>N$ , right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: So the endpoint $ b-1/n$ is taken to be a sequence. It is interesting that you use this to make a conclusion regarding sets. I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: Have I got the right idea? I don't want to go on about it but I've always thought of $\epsilon$ as being "small but arbitrary". But that was to show that a sequence converged. Here you've seen that $b-1/n$ converges to $b$ so the sequence $b-1/n$ can be made as close to $b$ as you like, which in this case is an $N$ where you have $\epsilon = b-x$.

Comment: @Ditherer Actually, I do not think it is that much of a surprise. See, your statement is not a statement about abstract set theory, but about real numbers, which are adaptated to topological reasonings. Moreover, notice that open intervals $(a,b)$ are actually open balls, for the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. In this context, it can actually be expected to use analytic (actually topologic) notions like limits.

Comment: Thank you, I shall look into that stuff. It's just that $b-x$ (epsilon) could be quite large, but it's not really about that. It's that for large enough $n$, we can make the distance between $b-1/n$ and $b$ as small as we please. So for this reason, we can have $\epsilon = b-x$

Answer (score 0):

Part 2:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

1) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n) \subset \mathbb{R}.$

Trivial.

Now show that $\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n)$.

2) Let $r$ be real, positive.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ with  $n>r.$

Hence $r \in (-n,n).$

2) Let $r <0.$

Then consider $-r >0.$

Archimedean principle :

There is a $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ with

$n >-r .$

Hence $-n < r$ , and $r \in (-n,n)$.

3)Let $r = 0;$  $0 \in (-1,1)$.

Altogether:

$\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n)$.

Comment: Ah, how is the first inclusion trivial?

Comment: Every $(-n,n) \subset$ R, i.e. every $x \in (-n,n)$ is in R. Hence the union is a subset of R, makes sense?

Comment: Okay, I can see that $(-n,n)$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ as it is only part of the real line, but how is the union a subset of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: To be specific, how is a union of subsets still a subset?

Comment: Let x be an element in Union (-n,n). Then x is in one (-n,n) , and since (-n,n) subset of R, then x in R.Is that ok?

Comment: Hi Peter, I think I get that. Thanks!

Comment: Ditherer 1.Welcome:))